# Anchor of a boat

Tags: water, buoyancy, displacement

hope you can help

I've been teaching my kids about pirates and when we were talking about pirate ships this morning I confused myself greatly.

When carrying an anchor a pirate ship (or any vessel with an anchor) is free to float about where ever the crew pleases, however once the anchor is in the water the ship is held in place.

This seems unusual as (according to Archimedes principal) the weight of the anchor when it's in the water is less than when it's on the ship (immersed weight = weight - weight of displaced fluid) so how come the boat can carry the anchor but as soon as the anchor hits the water the boat cannot move?

As you can see below the ship on the left can move freely, the one in the right cannot.
[image]

I thought of a few possible solutions but maybe I'm shooting in the dark here.

Initially I thought maybe the part of the anchor that curls out at the bottom is holding a large volume of water (much more than that which the anchor displaced) and so holds the ship in place, like a scoop.

The other idea I had was that maybe the anchor is on the bottom of the ocean but this seems absurd, I've read that the average depth of the ocean is around 14,000ft (obviously parts are much deeper) and a 30mm chain of that depth would weight almost 100,000kg, which not only seems like a lot for the boat to carry but also essentially adds to the weight of the achor itself, perplexing the question further still

Thanks for your time

Comment: That's so weird! I was thinking about this question just this morning. It's been rattling my brain all day! I hope someone can answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most [anchors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchor) have to "hook" into the seabed, so you will need a long chain (rode). In some cases, the rode can have several thousand feet and weigh 100 tonnes. But in most cases, ships won't anchor in deep water.

Note that the anchor's rode must be several times longer than the sea depth:

[image]

To remove the anchor, you just have to shorten the chain until it's vertical. Then you pull "up".

In deep water, see the: [sea anchor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_anchor), which is a kind of sea "brake".

[image]

Comment: OK so it's like a grappling hook of sorts, that makes sense, but how would the pirates then un-hook the anchor? Would a single ship then have an anchor, a sea anchor and a drougue? how would the pirates know the depth of the water, you can't see through it can you?

Comment: @Luke Updated the answer. Most ships I've seen use normal anchors. I don't know about the depth, but I guess they estimated it, used maps, saw the color, etc.

Comment: Besides, pirates never anchor until they 'Arrrrrrrrrrr' close to land :-)

Comment: You weight anchor (remove it from the sea bed and bring it aboard) by hauling on the line, this moves the ship *toward* the anchor until the angle is sufficient for it to unhook, and eventually lift off the sea bed. In some places it is possible for anchors to become so wedged in rocks on the sea floor that they can not be recovered which is a disaster of medium proportions, and is thankfully rare. Drogues *don't* stop the ship, they simply reduce the degree to which you move relative the water you're in, thus reducing the hazard presented by not actively piloting the vessel.

Answer (score 0):

The anchor is on the bottom of the ocean. It attaches to the seabed, as jinawee pointed out. In parts where the seabed is too deep to reach, they use a drogue or sea-anchor. Buoyancy doesn't really play a role in how either work.

Comment: Ok, sorry now I'm even more confused, if the anchor is always on the bottom of the ocean how do the pirates attach it to the sea bed? The idea of the drougue is similar to how I thought the regular anchor was working though.

Comment: @Luke: As far as I know, it's not always on the bottom of the ocean. It's only when they get near land, they lower it down and it grabs on to the sea floor (which is considerably less deep than 14,000ft when you're near a coastline). When traveling, they have it on board, not in the water.

Comment: Thanks @Doofus, does the Drogue cause problems with catching fish, isn't it essentially a huge trawler net?

Comment: Think parachute, rather than net.

Comment: @Luke: I assume they don't use the sea-anchor when they're fishing, because when they're fishing they're moving, so deploying the sea-anchor would defeat the point of having a moving boat in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The ship drops the anchor which, in virtue of the stock (rebatable or collapsible arm near the top, perpendicular to the plane of the flukes)(flukes = triangular "nails" which should grab the bottom if sandy or muddy, or hook to stony bottoms)
will, with the subsequent pulling of the vessel, dig one (or both) of the flukes into sandy/muddy bottom.
But this is the initial process.  The ship is not held in place by the anchor, but by the weight of the chain joining the anchor to the vessel. 
The safe norm is to let go three times the depth of the water in chain. if the weather is good and the current weak. In adverse conditions the ratio should be higher.
Once the anchor is on the bottom, and enough chain has been payed out (in modern ships by going astern with the engine after letting go anchor, to help keep the chain extended on the bottom) it is immaterial whether the anchor dug in or not.
It is the weight of the anchor and the long curve (aptly called a catenary curve in math and geometrym from ancient greek Katinis, chain)it describes, that keep the vessel in place.  If properly anchored, the chain and the curve act as a sort of spring, never transmitting the tension to the anchor.  An old maritime adage states that, properly done, and having enough chain, it is possible to anchor with a pin, instead of an anchor.
Enough chain should be payed out from the beggining. If this is not done, then the anchor will drag and the vessel can easily be lost.